# Gson JSON injection

Tags: java, json

I'm using Google's GSON lib to convert a string to a JSON collection.

```
String tmp = ....;
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Employee>>(){}.getType();

List<Employee> = gson.fromJson(tmp, collectionType);
```

When running it through a static analyzer, it's fails stating the call to gson.fromJson violates JSON Injection.

Can someone tell me if the Gson lib is safe?